# Как на js проверить существует ли картинка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я циклом получаю src картинок и создаю их, а как можно сделать так, чтобы картнка не создавалась если в папке она отсутствует?

Answer (score 5):

Создаёшь картинку, загружаешь. Если есть - onload, нет - onerror:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://site.ru/img.png';
img.onload = function(){alert('картинка существует')};
img.onerror = function(){alert('картинка не существует')};
```

Или такой вариант для логики отображения/скрытия:

```
<img src = "1.jpg" onerror = "this.style.display = 'none'">
```