# Получить все картинки в html документе - js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

мне надо получить ссылки всех изображений на сайте js/jQuery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/favicon.ico" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="/image/star/star.svg" alt="image"/>
        <img src="/image/star/star.jpg" alt="image"/>
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_light_color_92x30dp.png" alt="image"/>
        
        <p> some text of container for test http://site.com </p>
        <p> some text of container for test http://site.com/inage/image.png</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        let images = getAllImage();
        console.log(images);

        // [
        //  "http://mysite/image/favicon.ico" ,
        //  "http://mysite/image/star/star.svg" ,
        //  "http://mysite/image/star/star.jpg" , 
        //  "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_light_color_92x30dp.png" ,
        //  "http://site.com/inage/image.png"
        // ]

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Можете подсказать как это реализовать ?

Comment: http://site.com/inage/image.png не лишняя ссылка? она же просто текстом идет, картинка не отображается. а /image/favicon.ico тоже нужна?

Comment: да , я поэтому пример вывода и сделал

Comment: Я думаю над реализацией через `fetch` - получаем ссылки все , делаем запрос ссылки через `fetch` , в ответе получаем тип файла - ``css , js , png , svg`` - если это изображения тогда записываем в масив , я не ошибаюсь ?

Comment: может ссылки так проверять? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869385/Как-на-js-проверить-существует-ли-картинка

Comment: @Андрюха проверка состоит в том являеться это изображениям а не файлом js или другой ссылкой на сайт + ещё не все картинки имеют расширения.

Comment: ну так там в моей ссылке выше создается яваскриптом изображение..указывается его путь, и событие onload - успех - картинка..я просто попробовал в яваскрипте выполнить код с вашей ссылкой на изображение без расширения и получил успех,  а попробовал просто сайт - не успех..чем не проверка?

Comment: `onload`  у `img`  срабатывает когда загружено действительно изображение. в остальных случаях `onerror`

Comment: @Андрюха хм а это идея , но мне ещё надо получить тип расширения файла так как не все ссылки имеют его - скрипт должен выводить изображения и тип файла (png , jpg и тд);
я сперва обрезал конец ссылок и получал тип изображения так но позже увидел что изображения могу быть и без ссылки .

Comment: но по  Content-Type ответа сервера тоже не вариант - сервера фейсбука его не отдают либо у картинок текст. Я делал в свое время по Content-Type определение, что ссылка изображение. Но столкнулся вот с этим фейсбуком.

Comment: а как тогда проверить расширения файла ?

Comment: ну вы имете в виду тип файла? расширение, это чисто виндовое понятие. ну в php можно попробовать командами типа imagecreatefromjpeg, imagecreatefrompng  и так далее перебрать все функции, если успех в какой-нибудь то тип определен..такой вот кривой путь ))..но это на стороне сервера, а как в js на стороне клиента я пока  не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Через чистый JS:

```js
var srcList = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.container img').forEach(el => {
    srcList.push(el.src);
});

console.log(srcList);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/favicon.ico" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="/image/star/star.svg" alt="image"/>
        <img src="/image/star/star.jpg" alt="image"/>
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_light_color_92x30dp.png" alt="image"/>
        
        <p> some text of container for test http://site.com </p>
        <p> some text of container for test http://site.com/inage/image.png</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а /image/favicon.ico ??  автору вроде она тожа нужна

Comment: не обратил внимание на то, что нужно забрать еще и с тега head. Тут уже скорее всего не помогу. Как и с тем что автор хочет забрать ссылки на изображения из тега p

Comment: Как вариант пусть соберет все теги p, и проверит каждое слово (пока после символа не окажется пробел - если оказался значит новое слово, алгоритм базовый). Ну и пусть проверяет что в слове содержится формат изображений (.png, .jpeg, .jpg etc)

Comment: иногда попадаються изображения без формата пример - https://c.hit.ua/hit?i=35274&g=0&x=2&s=1&c=1&t=-180&w=1536&h=864&d=24&0.8902127423959483&r=https%3A//www.google.com/&u=https%3A//askdev.ru/q/kak-proverit-tip-fayla-mime-s-pomoschyu-javascript-pered-zagruzkoy-18453/

Comment: Я вот например думаю над тем что бы собрать все ссылки в документе и проверить их через fetch